# How to join on three different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to fill my table with Companynames, but they all come from another table (depending on type of company)

So, for example, i have a 'regardingobjectid' in my current table, which is equal to the 'id' from the table 'opportunity'. In this table 'opportunity' there is no companyname, only a 'parentaccountid' which refers to an 'Id' in the table 'account', in which the name is known.

So the regardingobjectid from my current table matches with an id in another table, from which I have to take another column to match with a column in ANOTHER table to get the name.

Does anyone have a clue on how to do it? I tried multiple left joins but I can't get it right.

I use SQL Server.

Here is a piece of my code from what I tried:

```
SELECT
e.regardingobjectid as CompanyId,
case
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'account' then a.name
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'lead' then l.companyname
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'opportunity' then o.name
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'incident' then a.name
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'contact' then a.name
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'salesorder' then a.name
end as Companyname
from emails e

left join opportunity o on e.regardingobjectid = o.id
left join account a on e.regardingobjectid = a.id
left join lead l on e.regardingobjectid = l.id
left join incident i on e.regardingobjectid = i.id
left join contact c on e.regardingobjectid = c.id
left join salesorder s on e.regardingobjectid = s.id
```

This fills my table for the categories account, lead and opportunity, but not for the categories incident, salesorder and contact.

In the tables opportunity, account, and lead are names. But, in the tables incident, contact and salesorder there are no names. The names from the salesorder, contact and incident labelled companies are in the account table.

For example, the CompanyId from this select statement is the same as 'id' from the table incident. In this table incident, there is an 'accountid' which corresponds to the 'id' in the table account, from which I want the name.

I managed to get the name for 'incident', but now my names for account are gone…
When i type my joins like this:

```
left join crm_systemuser u on p.owneridyominame = u.fullname
left join crm_incident i on i.id = p.regardingobjectid
left join crm_account a on a.id = i.blue10_accountid
left join crm_opportunity o on o.id = p.regardingobjectid
left join crm_account s on s.id = p.regardingobjectid
left join crm_lead l on l.id = p.regardingobjectid
```

My incidents, leads and opportunities fills with names. However, when I switch order:

```
  left join crm_account a on a.id = e.regardingobjectid
  left join crm_systemuser u on e.owneridyominame = u.fullname
  left join crm_incident i on i.id = e.regardingobjectid
  left join crm_account on a.id = i.blue10_accountid
  left join crm_opportunity o on o.id = e.regardingobjectid
  left join crm_lead l on l.id = e.regardingobjectid
```

My incidents are empty again but my accounts are filled with names…

Comment: sample data? show us a little more. don't make a secret out of it ;-)

Comment: Try [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some good ideas.

Comment: If I understood correctly, something like `SELECT
 a.accountName
FROM
 CurrentTable ct
 JOIN Opportunity o ON o.id = ct.regardingobjectid
 JOIN account a ON a.Id = o.parentaccountid` should work.

Comment: @EstebanP. I added some code, sorry! Finding it hard to explain my questions haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just left join up the chain, and use ISNULL until you get a value for company name.

```
SELECT ISNULL(o.companyname, a.companyname) CompanyName
FROM myCurrentTable t
LEFT JOIN Opportunity o ON t.regardingobjectid=o.id
LEFT JOIN Account a ON o.parentaccountid=a.id
```

If you know the values like in your updated example, you are correct to use the case statement.  The only issue is you had a few typos, using a.name three times in the case.  Try:

```
SELECT
e.regardingobjectid as CompanyId,
case
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'account' then a.name
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'lead' then l.companyname
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'opportunity' then o.name
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'incident' then ai.name
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'contact' then ac.name
  when e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'salesorder' then aso.name
end as Companyname
from emails e

left join opportunity o on e.regardingobjectid = o.id
left join account a on e.regardingobjectid = a.id
left join lead l on e.regardingobjectid = l.id
left join incident i on e.regardingobjectid = i.id
left join account ai on i.regardingobjectid = ai.id
left join contact c on e.regardingobjectid = c.id
left join account ac on c.regardingobjectid = ac.id
left join salesorder s on e.regardingobjectid = s.id
left join account aso on s.regardingobjectid = aso.id
```

There is another format for CASE that might make it easy to read, so my final answer would be:

```
SELECT
e.regardingobjectid as CompanyId,
case
  e.regardingobjectid_entitytype when 'account' then a.name
  when 'lead' then l.companyname
  when 'opportunity' then o.name
  when 'incident' then ai.name
  when 'contact' then ac.name
  when 'salesorder' then aso.name
end as Companyname
from emails e

left join opportunity o on e.regardingobjectid = o.id
left join account a on e.regardingobjectid = a.id
left join lead l on e.regardingobjectid = l.id
left join incident i on e.regardingobjectid = i.id
left join account ai on i.regardingobjectid = ai.id
left join contact c on e.regardingobjectid = c.id
left join account ac on c.regardingobjectid = ac.id
left join salesorder s on e.regardingobjectid = s.id
left join account aso on s.regardingobjectid = aso.id
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the companies labelled as opportunity. However I also have 4 other categories from which I need names, but they all come from different tables. I added a piece of my code in my question to clarify.

Comment: See my updated code above.  You had it right, but with a few typos.  I also provided an alternative at the end.

Comment: When I use this code, I get the error that i.name, c.name and s.name are invalid columns. There are no name columns on those tables, but I have to get the names from the account table. However, the regardingobject id is the same as id in the table, but then I have to get another id from that table to link to the account id for the name. Hope you understand.

Comment: For each additional account lookup add another link to the account table with a different alias.  I edited the answer above to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something called a [**Junction Table**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/map-many-to-many-relationships-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-2017) that makes it easy to join multiple tables together.

[image: Junction Table]

Answer (score 0):

A simplified example showing full joins conditions

```
select
  e.regardingobjectid as CompanyId
  ,coalesce(o.name, a.name, l.companyname, i.name, ...) as Companyname
from emails e
left join opportunity o on o.id  = e.regardingobjectid and  e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'opportunity'
left join account a on a.id = e.regardingobjectid and e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'account'
left join lead l on l.id = e.regardingobjectid and e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'lead' 
left join incident i on i.id = e.regardingobjectid and e.regardingobjectid_entitytype = 'incident' 
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is easier to read. But how do I get the name from the table account for the company labelled as 'incident'?

Comment: ín the coalesce sentence there is i.name, but there is no name column in the table incident. This doesn't work either... I'm still stuck

Comment: That was just an example, find the name of the column you want from indecent table, and use that instead